# Angular/Typescript Change values of a number array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I get the Object essensplan

```
  const essensplan = [
 { id: 1, essenProWoche: [11, 14, 17, 20, 12] },
 ...
 { id: 8, essenProWoche: [15, 14, 13, 12, 11] }
  ];
```

from an emulated server and I want the possibility for the user to change each value of the array essenProWoche
and give it back to the server.

I tried

```
    <div>
     <label>Änderungen:
        <input [(ngModel)]="essensplan.essenProWoche"     placeholder="Name">
     </label>
    </div>
```

which doesn't work because it's not returned as an array

and

```
 <label *ngFor="let id of essensplan.essenProWoche; let i = index">
    <input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="essensplan.essenProWoche[i]">
  </label>
```

which changes the values live in the browser, but they are not saved.

I save the inputs by the following functions:

essensplan-detail.component.ts

```
save(): void {
this.essensplanService.updateEssensplan(this.essensplan)
  .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
  }
```

essensplan.service.ts

```
 updateEssensplan(essensplan: Essensplan): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.put(this.speisekarteUrl, essensplan, httpOptions).pipe(
 tap(_ => this.log(`updated essensplan id=${essensplan.id}`)),
 catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateEssensplan'))
```

Comment: As you are saying: _I get the Object essensplan_, it should be `const essensplan ={ id: 1, essenProWoche: [11, 14, 17, 20, 12] };`

Comment: Why don't you use pick the input as a comma seperated values ?

Comment: @RohitSharma it is like that, there are following more with id:2, 3 and so on

Comment: @CruelEngine how does that work?

Comment: @anecsa Rohit has answered it here .

Answer (score 1):

Another way, you can make the array elements as a string. When you get an array of few objects from server:

```
this.essensplan = [
    { id: 1, essenProWoche: [11, 14, 17, 20, 12] },
    { id: 2, essenProWoche: [11, 14, 17, 20, 12] }
];
```

Then you can change it as:

```
this.essensplan.map(item => {
    item.essenProWoche = item.essenProWoche.join(',');
});
```

And you can use:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="essensplan">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.essenProWoche">
</ngtemplate>
<!-- but make sure to enter the values with commas -->
```

And when you are about to save it:

```
save(): void {
    this.essensplan.map(item => {
        item.essenProWoche = item.essenProWoche.split(',');    // because it was a string
    });
    this.essensplanService.updateEssensplan(this.essensplan)
    .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
}
```

Comment: thank you this looks like it will work, but what is the import for the .map()?

Comment: No need to import the `map` its available in `Array.prototype` by default.

Comment: this.essensplan.map wants to map the essensplan object and not the EssenProWoche array

Comment: As you can see above `this.essensplan = [ ]`. Its also an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call the save function automatically on change of each value? If yes, then use a `formControl` and subscribe to the `valueChanges` event. you can call your `save` function everytime the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want two-way binding functionality?

If you change value inside model than automatically update your json too.

**In Your html :**

```
<div *ngFor="let items of essensplan">
    <div *ngFor="let opt of items.essenProWoche; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">       
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="items.essenProWoche[i]">
    </div>
</div>
```

**In Your Ts :**

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
   return index;
}
```

For Live demo check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pff1v)

Comment: thanks, this works in browser! only problem is that it's not saved to the server, do you know how i can add that?

Comment: console gives no error, i think because the json is updated in the browser. It's just not saved to the server

Comment: Did you get updated json inside this method : `updateEssensplan(essensplan: Essensplan): Observable<any> {` in your service?